# How to use the Count query to return results from two different places?

Tags: sql, database, sparql, semantic-web, ontology

Here is my query:

```
prefix dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT COUNT (?x) AS ?numberIn_Horror, COUNT (?y) AS ?numberIn_Action 

WHERE { ?x dct:subject dbc:Horror_film . 
        ?y dct:subject dbc:Action_film .}
```

I get a numeric output for this query however, it does not match the actual value for the number of movies present in these genres.

Is there a way to change the query so it returns the number of movies accurately. 
Additionally, I am unsure as to what value it is currently returning.

Added Picture

[Game look-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BBXo.png)

Comment: is this your own data? I'm asking because in DBpedia the category is called `Horror_films`. And you should do `(COUNT (DISTINCT ?x) AS ?numberIn_Horror) (COUNT (DISTINCT ?y) AS ?numberIn_Action) ` because both triple patterns aren't connected, thus, the number is the cartesian. More efficient would be do use two subqueries. Especially because if one of both categories is empty, the whole result would be always 0

Comment: @UninformedUser Ah yes I thought to modify it would be ok my mistake. Okay so the returned value is the cartesian product of the two sets right. Could you write this as the answer

Comment: right, the cartesian of the bindings of ?x and ?y is the resultset, thus, you have a potentially larger number or just 0 when you do count on this resultset. Or, the other way is two nest to subqueries inside a query.

Comment: One more point, you prefix dbc: looks weird. I mean, the DBpedia namespace for categories is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:`

Comment: @UninformedUser Yess okay got it! I appreciate the help by the way. Okay so I have tried to apply that same logic to a game domain but it is returning 0 for each respective year - I have included a snapshot. I cannot identify an error

Comment: 1.) you local data uses the correct namespace in the URIs? 2.) The category names are correct? 3.) I mentioned it before, if one of those categories is empty, the result will be 0 for both

Comment: @UninformedUser Yeah the URIs etc are correct, Okay so If I want to get the value of both I have to change the select line I think

Comment: change what? I'd go with a different query which always leads to 2 columns independently of the number of categories you're counting: `prefix dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT ?category (count(?x) as ?cnt) 

WHERE {
{?x dct:subject ?category . FILTER (?category = dbc:Horror_films) } UNION {?x dct:subject ?category FILTER (?category = dbc:Action_films) }
}
group by ?category`

Comment: and nowadays one would use a more compact form, but I guess Protege SPARQL does not support this yet: `prefix dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT ?category (count(?x) as ?cnt) 

WHERE {
VALUES ?category {dbc:Horror_films dbc:Action_films}
?x dct:subject ?category
}
group by ?category`